# grep/touch -mtime check log within last XX minutes

Tags: linux, logging, grep, touch

i want to run a query on a linux machine. i want to check a log file and only check within the last 15 minutes. assuming there were changes and additions to the log file. what is the correct query?

**grep 'test condition' /home/somelogpath/file.log -mtime 15**

thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, unless each logged record has a timestamp or each record is logged in a different file.

Answer (score 0):

to check only files modified in the last hour:

```
find /path/to/logfiles -mtime -1 -print
```

so you could

```
find /path/to/logfiles -mtime -1 -print | xargs grep "some condition" /dev/null
```

(note : I add a file (/dev/null) so that grep will always have at least 2 files and thus will be forced to display the name(s) of the matching files.. As it's /dev/null, it won't match anything you grep, so you don't have the risk of seing "/dev/null" in the ouput of grep. But it serves its purpose: grep will prefix any match with the filename, even if only 1 file matched)

for minutes, etc, please check your :

```
man find
```

(it depends on your os, etc) (and I don't have a linux at hand right now)

If you meant "only match the last X seconds in a log file" :  use awk, and have a condition on the line (it depends on the logfile format.. if it uses "seconds since startup" or "epoch", you can simply test the relevant field to be >= some value. If it's using "2014-05-15 hh:mm" you can also find ways to do it, but it will be cumbersome..)